# C - What is this code line means?(about structs)

Tags: c, struct

If i want to define a struct in c i write

```
typedef struct ObjectP
{
   some code
}
```

and this is legal, but what about this code line ?

```
typedef struct Object* ObjectP
{
   some code
}
```

why there is a syntax error on the line **typedef struct Object* ObjectP**

Comment: what do you think is the meaning of the second piece of code?

Comment: i don't know, we have a header file that we must implement
and there is a struct that we have to implement and it is this struct
**typedef struct Object* ObjectP**

Answer (score 5):

That's not how you use `typedef` with structures. You have to put the type-alias name *after* the structure, like

```
typedef struct Object
{
    ...
} Object;
```

And if you want multiple type-aliases, you just add them to then end, as in

```
typedef struct Object
{
    ...
} Object, *ObjectP;
```

**Or** you separate the definitions:

```
struct Object
{
    ...
};

typedef struct Object Object;
typedef struct Object *ObjectP;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using wrong syntax for `typedef`ing the `struct` pointer.

Use:

```
typedef struct Object
{
   some code
}
*ObjectP;
```

Now you can use `ObjectP` to define pointers to this `struct` this way: `ObjectP ptr1_struct, ptr2_struct;`.

Comment: @JohnBode: I am sorry about that `*`, thanks for pointing out. I have corrected my answer

Answer (score 1):

Structure definition should end with "**;**". typedef is not part of structure definition. It is a renaming convention.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for a struct definition is

```
    struct identifieropt { struct-declaration-list }
```

The optional identifier is the struct *tag*; it's the name by which the struct type can be referenced.  For example:

```
struct foo { int x; int y; double z; };
```

`foo` is the tag for that struct type; I can then use `struct foo` anywhere I need a type name:

```
struct foo bar;
struct foo *fptr;
```

I can combine the struct definition and object declaration in one:

```
struct foo { int x; int y; double z; } bar, *fptr;
```

If I want to create a typedef name for a pointer to `struct foo`, I do it as follows:

```
typedef struct foo { int x; int y; double z} *FooP;
```

`FooP` is now a synonym for `struct foo *`:

```
FooP myptr;
```

is equivalent to

```
struct foo { int x; int y; double z; } *myptr;
```